# why my webpage is refreshing when i am calling a JavaScript function in my aspx page on a html image click event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i am using a html image control in mt aspx page and i am calling a javascript function on the click event of that control but here my page is getting refreshed every time i am clicking it

here's my code:

```
<input id="wbsnew1" type="image" value="New" onclick="showHideDiv()" src="images/New.png" />
```

and here's my javascript code :

```
function showHideDiv() {
        document.getElementById("newdata2").style.display = "block";
    }
```

"newdata2" is a div

Comment: Not enough information. Can you show us a little bit more of your html

Comment: what part? i can show u. do u need the "newdata2" div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="wbsnew1" type="image" value="New" onclick="return showHideDiv();" src="images/New.png" />

function showHideDiv() {
    document.getElementById("newdata2").style.display = "block";
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: thanks that solved it ... actually it was happening without return when it was button but i changed it to image.. is that the problem??

Comment: problem was actually, Input button causes postback and whether you were calling javascript function but the postback wasn't stopped, and return false did the work. so it was returning false and postback was stopped..

Comment: `<input type=button>` does not perform a form submit. only `<input type=submit>` and `<input type=image>` does

Answer (score 0):

Try to return after applying the function like the following code :

```
`<input id="wbsnew1" type="image" value="New" onclick="showHideDiv(); return false;" src="images/New.png" />`
```

also let your function return false

```
function showHideDiv() {  
     document.getElementById("newdata2").style.display = "block";

return false;
}
```

Comment: there is no need for the function to return false. it is enough for the `return false` statement in the handler.

Comment: sometimes in browsers the return inside the function will not solve such problems it happend with me many times i solved it by the return after applying the function

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the input tag is located inside some other html element that triggers reloading. Try stopping bubbling:

```
<input id="wbsnew1" type="image" value="New" onclick="showHideDiv(event)" src="images/New.png" />

function showHideDiv(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById("newdata2").style.display = "block";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="image" />` elements are used to submit the form (in ASP.NET that equals the postback).

You have few alternatives:

1. (best) Replace the `<input>` tag to `<img />`. The other attributes are the same (except the `type` attribute is not needed).
2. Add `return false` to the `onclick` handler: `<input onclick="showHideDiv(); return false;"`.
3. Return the `false` value from the method itself and add `return` keywork to the method

   ```
   <input onclick="return showHideDiv();" />

   function showHideDiv() {
       ....
       return false;
   }
   ```